# Camel csv creating issue

Tags: apache-camel

I need to create a csv file having some thing like following structure using Camel.

school1_id,school1_name
class1_id,class1_name,division1
student1_id,studennt1_firstname,student1_lastname
student2_id,studennt2_firstname,student2_lastname
class2_id,class2_name,division2
student1_id,studennt1_firstname,student1_lastname
student2_id,studennt2_firstname,student2_lastname

school2_id,school2_name
class1_id,class1_name,division1
student1_id,studennt1_firstname,student1_lastname
student2_id,studennt2_firstname,student2_lastname
class2_id,class2_name,division2
student1_id,studennt1_firstname,student1_lastname
student2_id,studennt2_firstname,student2_lastname

Seems like **bindy** is not supporting such hierarchical structure and in **beanio** reference it says, 
 "repeating segment may not contain repeating descendants with variable occurrences".
Is there any other approach or api which I can implement to create such a csv in apache Camel? I am using Camel 2.17.0

Comment: According to RFC 4180 the official specification for CSV see the link https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#page-2. There maybe an optional header line appearing as the first line of the file with the same format as normal record lines.  This header will contain names corresponding to the fields in the file  and should contain the same number of fields as the records in the rest of the file. So you are not really writting a CSV. Thus you would need a custom processor to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Namphibian. I am now trying to use super csv, since it supports such structures using its ListWriter.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to normalize it with a custom Processor.

An alternative would be to employ the [Spring Batch Component](http://camel.apache.org/springbatch.html) that has advanced strategies of [multi-line records](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#multiLineRecords).